# Transfer data from iOS to windows computer via BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to find some third party APIs from which I should be able to transfer files/data from iOS or Android device to windows devices via Bluetooth.

Any help will be appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: Why third party? Just set up a peripheral on the iOS side and connect to it from Windows.

Comment: In third party, I will not have to consider pairing, securing and writing extensive methods to send files in chunks they will be doing this part. So to save time I prefer third party SDK.

Comment: @Emil, Actually I want to connect from iOS device or Android Device to Windows on demand and transfer something.